# websocket sample program: Not getting callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I have created one server and client. Which is working perfectly. But I have to implement it with callback. Which is coming undefined.

My code: 
**server side code**

```
var net = require('net');
var HOST = '127.0.0.1';
var PORT = 6969;
net.createServer(function(socket) {    
    console.log('CONNECTED: ' + socket.remoteAddress +':'+ socket.remotePort);
    socket.on('data', function(data, callback) { 
      console.log('Data from client :' + data + '\n');
      return callback('error', 'message');
    });
}).listen(PORT, HOST);
console.log('Server listening on ' + HOST +':'+ PORT);
```

**Client side code**

```
var net = require('net');
var HOST = '127.0.0.1';
var PORT = 6969;
var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(PORT, HOST, function() {
    console.log('CONNECTED TO: ' + HOST + ':' + PORT);
});

client.write('I am Chuck Norris!', function(error, response){
  console.log(error, response);
});
```

**I am getting this error in server side**

```
/web/ws/server.js:10
      return callback('error', 'message');
             ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/web/ws/server.js:10:14)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:764:14)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:426:10)
    at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:422:5)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:165:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:127:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:528:21)
```

**client side result**

```
CONNECTED TO: 127.0.0.1:6969
undefined undefined
```

** I have tried with socket.io which is working fine.
** But criteria is 'net' package

Am I missing something ? Is it possible to work with callbacks here ? Please make me understand. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `data` event handler in the `net` library doesn't have a callback function. e.g:

```
socket.on('data', function (chunk) {

});
```

If you want to catch the event for when all the data is consumed you can use:

```
socket.on('end', function () {

});
```

Your code would look like this:

```
var chunks = [];

socket.on('data', function (chunk) {
    chunks.push(data);
});

socket.on('end', function (chunk) {
    chunks = chunks.join('');
});
```

Comment: Ya I tried with that. This is working fine. But is it possible to implement callback on it ? Because I need it :(

Comment: No you can't. But why do you need the callback itself rather than just ```res.write()``` and ```res.end()``` ?

Comment: Its the clients demand. Lets see what I can do. Thanks for the info